# Can we get an support for autolinking ppas?

Tags: feature-request

It would be really nice if ppas would be autolinked in questions/answers/comments.

E.g. if I write ppa:ondrej/sandbox, it would be automatically linked to https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/sandbox

O.

Answer (score 3):

How often do we really link to PPA's using their fully-qualified PPA name?

The system *doesn't* provide a built-in facility for:

- surrounding text [with `<kbd>` tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts),
- creating [package installation links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2405/ask-ubuntu-toolbar-buttons-a-set-of-toolbar-buttons-for-ask-ubuntu-that-make-i),
- or even posting [pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)!

Instead, these features are provided by user scripts (see links above).

This seems like a problem that would be solved well with a user script (that could be used by anyone who *wanted* to create PPA links in an automated fashion). But there is probably no good reason for the system to treat them as URL's.

And **there is already a user script that does this**. The same one that does package installation links will also make PPA links. (If for any reason people want a script that *just* creates PPA links, someone could make that.)

I recognize that what I am suggesting is *not equivalent* to this feature request. What I am suggesting would not automatically turn all text of the form `ppa:username/ppaname` into a link to a PPA, in all posts and comments. But is there any major advantage of that very broad change, compared to simply popularizing the tools we already have to create PPA links efficiently?

Answer (score -1):

Everything is possible as all of we know and this also but not that much easy.

Every PPA have its own build for different version of Ubuntu. so if we place `ppa:ondrej/sandbox` then how it have to take ? I mean is it belongs to precise version of Ubuntu or Raring version. that should also to consider.

Comment: The suggestion here is *not* for an installation link (which would probably be a bad idea, considering that there is some degree of risk associated with installing software from a PPA). Rather, it's asking for a link to the Launchpad page for the PPA. That page lists all the releases the PPA supports an provides information about what packages the PPA supplies and how to install the PPA.